# continuous deployment of web application built with multiple packages

Tags: javascript, continuous-delivery, reactjs, gitlab, npm

Our react web application is broken down to multiple components. Some of these components are part of the same git mono repo and some live in a different repo.

Now, to implement a bug fix we have to update the changes in one repo, release a version of the package, update the tree of dependencies, release other intermediatory packages and then we finally update the react web application.

This feels very a bit waterfall and not continuous. Additionally, we are optimized for package delivery versus web product delivery. Is there a solution which allows us to continuously get the latest and once in a while we release a new version of the libraries?

Comment: Once I was told that there are "tools" which help it, and provided https://github.com/lerna/lerna as example. I cannot say anything if it helps, but you could take a look at it.

Comment: Mono repo tools like lerna work for 1 repo. What if the packages were in separate repos?

Answer (score 2):

A solution I see to this is having your CI/CD process on the main package ensure child packages are updated. Using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) you could set and fixate your package version `major version` and `minor version` number but ensure you always have the latest `patch version`.

This way, whenever a child package has a new patch, your build process will pick that up, and install it. Whenever a major or minor version update occurs you'll have to update your set version numbers accordingly, which will require you to check if the update didn't break anything etc...

The main assumption in this approach is that you adhere to using the semantic versioning principles.

Depending on the build system you are using, there might be ways (via webhooks orso) to trigger new builds on the main package whenever a child package has a new version.

Comment: Of course, you need this. However, the challenge here each time you make a change to a downstream package, you need to release a new version. This means each commit is a new release for the package.

Alternatively, you wait for a period of time (say a week) to accumulate changes and then release the package version. This does not give you continuous delivery